# yii how to connect two options

Tags: jquery, database, yii

I have two fields, the first one is called `customer name` and the other one is called `customer id`. How can I do to reach such effect, when I enter the customer name in the first textfield, the second field (probably a dropdownlist)will immediately show his/her id after name is found exist.

So, can anyone give me a simple example of achieving this purpose. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a one-dimensional array that has all of your customer names, e.g. `array('Bob', 'Sally', 'Fred');`

Then you can use CJuiAutoComplete and CHtml::dropDownList together by doing something like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
    'attribute'=> 'Customer_name',
    'model' => $model,
    'sourceUrl' => array('customer/aclist2'),
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'1',
        'select' => "js: function(event, ui){ $('#".CHtml::activeId($model, 'Customer_id').").val(ui.item.value); }"
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:20px;',
    ),
));
echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'Customer_id');
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList(
  $model,
  'Customer_id',
  CHtml::listData(Customer::model()->findAll(), 'Customer_name', 'Customer_id'
));
```

You will need to adjust the names of the model (Customer) and attributes (customer_name, customer_id) to match yours. Tested with my own data.

Comment: But I found an error message appears: Customer ID cannot be blank. In fact the customer ID changed when I typed its corresponding customer name, but this error message showed when I press button to save changes into database. So, how to solve this problem. I seems yii cannot recognize the data in the dropdownlist (But it actually show the corresponding ID).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think to mention this: when you submit a form for a model, the field's id has to be in this format - `Customer_Customer_id` and the field's name has to be in this format - `Customer[Customer_id]`. Otherwise the model can't recognize it as one of its attributes. When you use dropDownList, the id and name are not set for you automatically. You can solve this by using activeDropDownList. I will update my code above. You also need to adjust CJuiAutocomplete, so I will edit that part as well

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the meaning. Would you mind to post the modified code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed my answer above to have the updated code. I based it off the code you posted so the attributes should be correct. I didn't include the surrounding div or Customer_name label though, just a warning.